# R httr content-type image

Tags: r, httr

I'm making a POST request to [this](https://pathways.embl.de/tools.cgi) website, and I'm expecting an XML object in return. Using the `httr` package in R:

```
library("httr")
url <- "https://pathways.embl.de/mapping.cgi"
#body <- list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
body <- list(selection = "R01324 W20 #ff0000", export_type="svg")

r <- POST(url, body = body, encode = "form", verbose())
```

This will return `status_code` 200 (success), but `content(r)` gives something like:

```
[1] 3c 3f 78 6d 6c 20 76 65 72 73 69 6f 6e 3d 27 31 2e 30 27 20 65 6e 63 6f 64 69 6e 67 3d 27 49
  [32] 53 4f 2d 38 38 35 39 2d 31 27 3f 3e 0a 3c 21 44 4f 43 54 59 50 45 20 73 76 67 20 50 55 42 4c
  [63] 49 43 20 22 2d 2f 2f 57 33 43 2f 2f 44 54 44 20 53 56 47 20 31 2e 30 2f 2f 45 4e 22 20 22 68
  [94] 74 74 70 3...
```

(output truncated)
which is definitely not xml.

Checking `r$headers$content-type` returns `"image/svg+xml"`.

I can do the equivalent in Python:

```
import requests

url = 'https://pathways.embl.de/mapping.cgi'
body = {"selection":"R01324 W20 #ff0000", "export_type":"svg"}

r = requests.post(url, data=body)

with open('test.svg','w') as file:
    file.write(r.text)
```

And this will successfully write out my desired xml output in `test.svg`.

I'd like to know how this can be done in `R`?

Answer (score 0):

Easier fix than I thought: `content(r, "text")`